# How to create two requests with different delay time jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load

i have the following scenario:

every 5 seconds a new user will be added and send ping

each user will ping every 5 minutes

each user will upload file every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way is going for [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) like:

1. To get request running each 5 seconds set "Target Throughput" to 12 requests per minute (1 request each 5 seconds)

   [image: JMeter request each 5 seconds]

   So you will have requests firing as per your requirement:

   [image: JMeter Constant Throughput Timer]
2. For request which needs to be executed once per 5 minutes do the same but set "Target Throughput" to `0.2`

   [image: JMeter run request each 5 minutes]

See [How to use JMeter's Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) for more information.

---

You may be also interested in [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which is more precise and advanced version.

Comment: what is the value should i use in timer for upload file each half hour?

Comment: Something like `0.033333`

Answer (score 0):

For a new user every 5 seconds use Ramp up period 5 times the number of threads.

Add to your Thread Group a [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with 6 Loop count, inside put ping request,

Add as a child to your ping request a [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) with 300000 milliseconds (5 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds).

> timers are processed before each sampler in the scope in which they are found

**After** Loop Controller add upload file sampler

In [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) You can define Scheduler (checkbox) with Duration you want the test to run.

> When using the scheduler, JMeter runs the thread group until either the number of loops is reached or the duration/end-time is reached - whichever occurs first.

Comment: why constant timer of 5000 milliseconds? should not be 300000 milliseconds (5 min)

Comment: another thing you cannot add a loop controller to a test plan only to thread group

Comment: Searched the net for about 1/2 hour how to add loop controller to test plan :)

Comment: something does not work as expected. i expect that from 0 to 5 min users are added but will not ping (this actually works correct), then from 5 min to 10 min users will start pinging (this also works correct) but from 10 min to 15 min i will expect users from the start of the list will start pinging together with actual users (two pings in a road) but this is not happening

Comment: see following image, this is what i expect from script https://i.imgur.com/0YmYxfA.jpg